# Chrome Flash Player (Pepper) date timezoneOffset bug

Tags: apache-flex, google-chrome, date, flash

I had a hard time finding anything on this critical problem so I decide to post this to help users running into the same issue.

The Chrome embedded Flash Player (Pepper) has a bug concerning date timezoneOffset that leads to some unpredictable behaviors when your application deals with dates.
As we provide a commercial Flex calendar component (KC-Calendar), this issue is critical for our clients and for their applications.

The issue details can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=154060
(please vote)

Waiting for a fix, if someone has a workaround, it could be really helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can disable the Chrome's flash player in the about:plugins page, then expand the details(on the right side of the page) and disable flash player in the user's directory.

Comment: Thanks to add this information there but unfortunately it is not a procedure you can easily explain to all your customers. Note: if you install the Adobe Flash Player abd disable the embeded Flash Player in Chrome the bug goes away.

Comment: We face the same issue. The bug is fixed in Chrome 23.0.1271.52. It may take time before this version is deployed to all platforms. We mitigate the problem by periodically checking if the timezone has changed, and use UTC dates wherever possible.

Answer (score 1):

We've dealt with such issues before, and honestly--rather than playing around with trying to serialize Dates--IMO the best solution (unless you WANT auto timezone conversion) is to simply pass date data types as strings. We do this cleanly using Java and ActionScript getters/setters which (correctly) set the serialized "date" objects in our DTO by parsing the un-adjusted date strings.

Ex. when you set a Date object's value, in the setter you convert Date to String & set a String field for that date. In the getter you get the String value for that date and parse it, returning a new Date object. Do this on server and client side.

The only minor caveat, obviously, is that you need to ensure the Flex & server side String-to-Date/Date-To-String functions use the same date format. Just put a nice comment explaining this (so nobody screws with it) next to your serialization date parsers/formatters and you're fine.

I expect this issue will probably go away once an HTML5-based Flex compiler is released (it's really just a Flash feature which isn't the desired behavior in our cases).